# <p> tag isn't positioning correct

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I made a `.wrapper` to be the main container, its width is 980px. And other `<div>` inside main container has 960px width. by using `margin: 0 auto`, each of the `<div>` tags will keep a 10px space to its main container. It's working well in my header and navigation bar. However when I start to input text in my `#1st_container` by using `<p>` tag, this 10px space effect is not working anymore, text shows up in main container. I tried a few way try to fix this but none is working and I have no idea what cause this..

How can I fix it?

P.S. it's looks fine in dreamweaver, just like it supports to be, but once I view the site in any browser, this 10px space is gone.

```css
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #DDDDDD;
 }

#header h1 {
 /*font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;*/
 /*font-family: "Veneer" Gadget, sans-serif;*/
 font-family: "Maven pro", sans-serif;
 font-size: 70px;
 font-weight:900;
 line-height:70px;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(122, 131, 175, 1);
 color:#FFF;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index:1;
}

.wrapper {
 height: 2024px;
 width: 980px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color:#FFF;
}
#header {
 height: 380px;
 width: 960px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: -20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 background:url(../image/header_bg.jpg) repeat; 
}
span.profile{
 font-size:50px;
 }
span.head_line{
 background:url(../image/line.png) no-repeat;
 width: 250px;
 height: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 20px 12px 25px;
 }
span.name {
 color: #b46b6b;
 }
span.this_is{
 font-size: 50px;
 }
#nav {
 height: 40px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:url(../image/nav_bg.png) repeat;
 text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 8px;
 }
#nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 }

#nav ul li a:link{
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 100;
 color:#4a4949;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 padding: 0 30px;
 }
#1st_container {
 width: 960px;
 height: 380px;
 margin: 0 auto; 
}
#2nd_container {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TB hompage</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="header"><h1>Hello<br />
      <span class="this_is">This is</span><br />
                     <span class="name">1st Website</span><br />
                     <span class="head_line"></span>& <span class="head_line"></span><br />
                     <span class="profile">I'm a new beginner</span> </h1>

      </div><!-- header end -->
<div id="nav">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Bref</a>
            <li><a href="#">example</a>
            <li><a href="#">example</a>
            <li><a href="#">example</a>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- navbar end here-->
<div id="1st_container">
<p>here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.</p>

</div>
<div id="2nd_container">here is 2nd content</div>
<div id="3nd_container">here is 3nd content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ID names can't start with a number as first character...That's why the styles are ignored

Comment: I did not notice a p tag in your CSS. You may want to try giving the p tag CSS properties. 
`p { margin:0; padding:0`

Comment: @Danko - They can in HTML5.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for point that but in this case that's the reason the styles are ignored

Comment: i see by doctype of the question this is not html5...so id tags cannot start with numbers here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have not closed a bunch of tags right like the li items. you dont have to give < br / > jusr < br > is enough. then I removed body css margin,padding property ( either that or ass a seperate css for < p > like margin:10px

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#header h1 {
  /*font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;*/
  /*font-family: "Veneer" Gadget, sans-serif;*/
  font-family: "Maven pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(122, 131, 175, 1);
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 2024px;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
#header {
  height: 380px;
  width: 960px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: url(../image/header_bg.jpg) repeat;
}
span.profile {
  font-size: 50px;
}
span.head_line {
  background: url(../image/line.png) no-repeat;
  width: 250px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 12px 25px;
}
span.name {
  color: #b46b6b;
}
span.this_is {
  font-size: 50px;
}
#nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../image/nav_bg.png) repeat;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
#nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
#nav ul li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #4a4949;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
#first_container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
  margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Hello<br>
      <span class="this_is">This is</span><br>
                     <span class="name">1st Website</span><br>
                     <span class="head_line"></span>& <span class="head_line"></span><br>
                     <span class="profile">I'm a new beginner</span> </h1>

  </div>
  <!-- header end -->
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Bref</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">example</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">example</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">example</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- navbar end here-->
  <div id="firstst_container">
    <p>here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.here is the 1st content.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="second_container">here is 2nd content</div>
  <div id="third_container">here is 3nd content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Blacktea - glad to be of help.If you found my answer acceptable please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2):

You set the width for the `header` and `nav` elements - you need to set it for the `.1st_container` element as well.

**Update:** no, it's not that - it's that your id's are starting with numbers. Can't do that.

http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Here's a codepen with the fix applied:
http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/vskep